# Setting and integer to a decimal with no error. Combobox that rejects non integer values

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

This is my first attempt at using vba in excel and my first programming in a long time. I am trying to create a combobox that rejects any input other than the integers 1-9. It is possible to select the value from the dropdown, but if you input text or something outside the range then click select i want it to clear and reprompt the userform. It is working well with text and numbers outside the range, but not if it is a decimal value in the range.

My basic idea was that there would be an error if the input was text or a decimal when i tried to set it to my declared integer variable, but it seems to round the number to an integer if it is a decimal. Is this standard for integer variables? There is probably an easier way to do the same thing, but I am also interested in the way this works.

here is the logic part:

```
Public offdays As Integer          'declared at start

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'click the select commandbutton on the userform

On Error GoTo errorhandler:

offdays = ComboBox1.Value          'set offdays = to combobox value
range ("K3") = offdays             'print the value to a cell

If offdays >= 0 And offdays <= 10 Then
   Unload Me
   Exit Sub
End If

errorhandler:
Unload Me
store_offdays.Show 

End Sub
```

Comment: Declare your variable as `Single` or `Double` instead of `Integer`. The latter doesn't hold decimal points which the `Single` and `Double` does. So basically, yes that is the standard for Integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, to capture decimal places, declare variables as `Single` or `Double`.
Integers only holds whole numbers.
But if your variable may accept other data types, then just declare it as `Variant`.
As for accomplishing what you want, you can try below:

```
Dim offdays As Variant

offdays = ComboBox1.Value
If Not offdays Like "[1-9]" Then Unload Me: Exit Sub
```

Above strictly accepts numbers `1-9` (single digit) only as input.
No text, no decimal, no zeros.
Hope this helps.